# how to get an object to follow the path in java

Tags: java, search, game-development

I have implemented an A* search which produces a path to the player( which is at the moment a blue ball). I would like to make the enemey(which is at this moment a red ball) to follow this path. I have tried incrementing the enemy's x and y coordinates depending on the distance from the x and y of the path but it doesn't work. I also tried other stuff which all haven't worked. Could you please advise me on how I can get the red ball following the path.

```
time++;
    if (time % speed == 0) {
        path = aStar.search(g, start(), target());

        if (path != null) {
       //converting  to coordinates
        pathX = (path.get(path.size() - 1).getElement() / board.getRowNum()) * pixelSize;
        pathY = (path.get(path.size() - 1).getElement() % board.getRowNum()) * pixelSize;


            if (x < pathX) {
                if (left != 0) {
                    this.x = pathX;
                }
            }
            if (x > pathX) {
                if (right != 0) {
                    this.x = pathX;
                }
            }
            if (y < pathY) {
                if (up != 0) {
                    this.y = pathY;
                }
            }
            if (y > pathY) {
                if (down != 0) {
                    this.y = pathY;
                                        }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The A* algorithm should return a list of coordinates. The first coordinate should be the location where the enemy should move. There should be no need to compute, or check, the x and y values.

Comment: it returns an arraylist of nodes. each node holds an index of the position in the array, thats why i have to convert the index to coordinates. But the problem i am having is not with the astar. my problem is how to get the red ball following the astar path. how do i get this object following those coordinates